# Keys in info.plist for localizations

Tags: iphone, ios, localization

Just wanted to know what are the keys in info plist which affects localization of iOS app.

Or which keys we needs to consider when develop localized application.

I have read documentation for,

1) CFBundleLocalizations
2) CFBundleDevelopmentRegion.

Regarding 1. for which functionality this key is for.

Regrading 2. As per apple doc if we set this key, and if our app has not language bundle which user has selected in user preferences then os will load default bundle which is set in front of this key in info.plist. I have tested this and this is not working for my code. Instead it loads the bundles according to the first available bundle in user preference languages.

Apart from above two keys is there any key which I need to consider while localization.